# create external panel in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, bootstrap-4, admin

I chose a news wordpress theme and I wanted to know if it was possible to create a separate panel to be able to manage that theme, something that would make it easier for the user to manage since the default panel is not very friendly

I tried to install a managed plugin but it only changes the initial screen, it does not change the complete interface

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to think about using a plugin like Elementor, Bricks or BeaverBuilder or on of those other once. Or a Full Site Editor Theme.

If you are not the developer of that theme and want to build a UI to change that theme. Then that Theme is not the right choice.

Think about it like this. Buying a theme with a fixed set of options is simply what you get 9 out of 10 times.

You get my drift?